# Simulating a network that trained with ADAPT

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I used ADAPT for incremental training a simple network, and i know that ADAPT changes weights and biases,i used this:

```
clc
clear all
net = linearlayer([0 1 2]);
pi = {[1; 1] [2;2]};
p = {[3 ;4] [5; 6] [7;8]};
t={[40; 50; 60] [10 ;20; 30] [70;60;50]};
net=configure(net,p,t);
net.inputweights{1}.learnparam.lr=0.001
net.adaptParam.passes = 10;
for i=1:1
[net,y,E,pf,af] = adapt(net,p,t,pi);
end
```

after that i simulate that network with the same input:

```
y1=sim(net,p,pi);
```

I expect that y =y1, but the results y1 and y are not equal!!
Why there is differnce betweet network output training with ADAPT(y) and the output of the trained network(y1)!?
What does ADAPT do?

Answer (score 0):

there you have it:

```
net = linearlayer([0 1 2]);
pi = {[1; 1] [2;2]};
p = {[3 ;4] [5; 6] [7;8]};
t = {[40; 50; 60] [10 ;20; 30] [70;60;50]};
net = configure(net,p,t);
net.inputweights{1}.learnparam.lr = 0.001;
net.adaptParam.passes = 10;

view(net)

[net,y,E,pf,af] = train(net,p,t);

tout = net(p);
```

You would use adapt() for post training applications. The matlab documentation specifically says that you use adapt after it has been trained and the network adapts as it is simulated (http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/adapt.html)

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU BRIAN.
So i shoud use ADAPT after training? like this code?

```
net = linearlayer([0 1 2]);
pi = {[1; 1] [2;2]};
p = {[3 ;4] [5; 6] [7;8]};
t = {[40; 50; 60] [10 ;20; 30] [70;60;50]};
net = configure(net,p,t);
net.inputweights{1}.learnparam.lr = 0.001;
net.adaptParam.passes = 10;

view(net)

[net,y,E,pf,af] = train(net,p,t);

tout = net(p);
for i=1:100
[net,y,E,pf,af] = adapt(net,p,t,pi);
end
```

If yes,is this incremental training!?

Comment: This is correct, but your "p" and "t" in your for loop would not be the same as the values you trained the model with... Hope this helps.